# Why is fstat not equal to stat?

Tags: macos

The code is supposed to watch for filesystem changes, but fstat is producing different results than stat, why?

```
struct stat info;
struct stat finfo;
char *path = "test";
int fd = open(path, O_EVTONLY);
if (fd <= 0){
    exit(-1);
}
wait_for_write(fd);
int err = fstat(fd, &finfo);
if (err){
    exit(-1);
}
err = stat(path, &info);
if (err){
    exit(-1);
}
if (finfo.st_mtimespec.tv_sec != info.st_mtimespec.tv_sec){
    //This happens!
    exit(-1);
}
```

`finfo.st_mtimespec.tv_sec` is the value corresponding to the time before the write occured and `info.st_mtimespec.tv_sec` is the value corresponding to after

Comment: One function is never "equal" to another.

Comment: Perhaps because a symbolic link is involved, or because another process is doing something on the same file...

Comment: Well, what is the difference between the two values? Any hints there?

Comment: `if (fd <= 0){
    exit(-1);` should be `if (fd == -1){
    exit(-1);`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch nope, there is no other process (or thread) touching this file and it isnt a symbolic link

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Both `stat` and `open` resolve symbolic links, AFAIK.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yea, the finfo value is the old value (before the write) and the info value is the value after the write

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch lstat is the one that doesnt resolve links

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit notice the line `wait_for_write(fd);` This waits for the file to be modified. Im sorry if I confused you when I said `nope, there is no other process (or thread) touching this file`. I meant that there is no other process touching the file in between the fstat call and the stat call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O_EVTONLY caches the modified time for successive queries.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `finfo.st_mtimespec.tv_sec`, as it is internal to the implementation; use `finfo.st_mtime` instead. (this is not the answer to your 'problem', but it may avoid related problems in the future)

Comment: it is inside an OS X specific implementation (guarded by #defines) so I think that it should be fine

Comment: 'it should be fine' is no reason to do it. Looks like cargocult-programming to me. What is wrong with .st_mtime anyway?

Comment: if do man fstat on osx, you'll see that st_mtime is not part of the stat struct

Comment: I see, it's a BSD-ism: I rest my case. Could it be possible that the O_EVTONLY open mode (which is relatively new) decouples the information in the system file table from the inode(cache) in order to avoid too much traffic to the inode cache? I suggest you check the kernel source.

Comment: +1: This seems to cover it. If the value is implementation-specific, I see no reason that the implementation can't cache it on `open`.

Comment: I don't know, but it is entirely possible that the system filetable has it's own copy of the [cma]time, and that these are not flushed too frequently into (or from?) the inode cache or even inodes on disk.

Comment: The problem may well be that its cached due to O_EVTONLY (although, it seems illogical to cache modified times for succesive queries to stat) but that is a seperate issue from using `finfo.st_mtimespec.tv_sec` (i.e. change this answer to match the comment or add a new answer)